# How to generate a ascii char in a string with Bash / ZSH correctly?

Tags: bash, character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to generate a string of `10` followed by a `NULL` (`\0`) followed by a `10`.

However `echo "10\010"` does not seem to work (I'm guessing it generates two chars - a `10` followed by `\010`. I'm not sure how to separate / escape these values / characters?

I've also tried `echo "10""/0""10"` which had the same result.

I'm piping this output to a named pipe.

Comment: please add what should be the expected output

Comment: His question is obvious, see my answer. Don't care the uninformed people that downvoted it...

Comment: The expected output is described in the first sentence. Not sure how else to 'present' the value otherwise.

Comment: Well you _could_ have spelled `␀` correctly.  (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a POSIX compliant shell you could use:

```
echo '10\000010'
```

note that `echo` requires three octal numbers to follow a `\0` to terminate an octal escape sequence.

The problem in your case is that `bash` is not POSIX compliant in this case as it does not implement `XSI` support that is required for a non-embedded UNIX variant.

`bash` however partially supports `printf` and so you could use:

```
printf '10\00010\n'
```

Comment: I never knew this was in octal notation. Thanks for the informative answer!

Comment: `printf` also understands hexadecimal notation: `10\x0010`.

Comment: No, `printf` in general does not understand hex notation. This only applies to `bash` and it's builtin command `printf`.

Comment: The posix spec require up to three octal numbers **or less** [Write an 8-bit value that is the zero, one, two, or three-digit octal number num](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_05).

Comment: bash echo expands backslash if called with the `-e` option **or** if the option `shopt -s xpg_echo` has been set.

Comment: The POSIX standard does not permit an `echo` implementation that honors a `-e` option and the POSIX standard requires to honor backslas escapes unless the shell has only been certified for embedded systems. BTW: it is possible to compile `bash` in a way that let it's `echo` implementation behave correctly. This is how Apple passed the POSIX certification.